# STATIC_ROOT setup in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, static, django-staticfiles, django-1.8

I was tried n I can't set-up as per official documents... 
I am attaching IMG here, pls give me suggestions, Where is the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk1s1.png)

Or, give me simple steps for it with dictionary tree structure.

Thank you.

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root', 'static')


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    # '/var/www/static/',
)
```

Comment: there's issue in your STATIC_ROOT  value you should not add single quotes as os.path.join is a function

Comment: same kind of error !
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4LK2pAXZXdoaU1JMzFEV29JNkE

Comment: Why do you keep posting screenshots? Your code is *text*, post it here.

Comment: sorry for that, I was posted code above.  @deniel Roseman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT = 'os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root', 'static')` can't work.

Try this :

```python
# define your base directory
# It will be `absolute/path/to/demo3`
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# define where your static files will be collected
# It will be `absolute/path/to/demo3/static`
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# keep it empty for the moment
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)
```

You have to understand `STATICFILES_DIRS` role :

> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to
>   a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your
>   apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your
>   settings file where Django will also look for static files.

**I recommend you to read carefully Django docs : [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css)**

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root', 'static')` This Works. Thank You

Comment: @BrijeshKalkani Thanks it worked! I was stuck while deploying Django app on Azure web app.

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` should be without quotes:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Also, the `STATIC_ROOT` folder shouldn't be named the same as the `STATICFILES_DIR` folder, so you should name it something like `staticfiles` instead:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')`

Comment: I was follow your instruction... But same kind of error !!

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear in stating the `STATIC_ROOT` is not a filesystem path. Django requires that `STATIC_ROOT` be an absolute path to a folder location on the machine. This error likely means that your resulting `STATIC_ROOT` is a partial or relative path.  What is the value of `BASE_DIR`? After the line that sets `STATIC_ROOT` and a `print(STATIC_ROOT)` to see what value it is.

Try setting `BASE_DIR` as follows:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

---

**Other Errors**

On the line

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')'
```

You have the value surrounded by single quotes. `os.path.join()` is a function call. Remove the quotes and change the line like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Also, STATIC_ROOT cannot be included in the list of files in STATICFILES_DIRS. Consider setting the STATIC_ROOT folder to:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```

Comment: Same error !
New screen-shot... 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4LK2pAXZXdoaU1JMzFEV29JNkE

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT = 'os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')'`  is a string which is wrong.

it should be `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Answer (score 0):

when creating the project with latest version of python and django in settings.py file by default `from pathlib import Path` Statement is there.So in that case no need to use `os.path`.

```
from pathlib import Path # Import First

STATIC_ROOT = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, 'static_collected')
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

I added one line code and it worked for me, I hope it doesn't pain in the future :)

```
import os
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to create a `static` folder in your root directory and also create the `static` folder in your `project` folder. Then your file structure would be:

```
demo3
    /demo3/staticfiles # collection folder for all static files
    /static            # root static folder
    /userForms/static  # your app static files
# OR
demo3
    /demo3
    /static_files     # collection folder for all static files
    /static           # root static folder
    /userForms/static # your app static files
```

Add this to your settings.py 
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'demo3', 'staticfiles')`
OR depending on where you want the collection folder 
`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')` 
Run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Then it would bundle all static files in project `staticfiles` OR root `static_files` folder, depending on where you want them.