# {% extends "base.html" %} not connecting static

Tags: html, django

I have included django-allauth into my site. It works but no styles on account pages, although index.html, that extends 'base.html'  as well renders normal styles.
 I have project structure like this:

```
root
 -myproject
 -myapp
 -templates/
    base.html
    index.html
     ....
    --/accounts/
       login.html
       logout.html
       .....
 -static/
    --admin/
      ---css
      ---js
      ---img
    --static/
      ---css
      ---js
 -media
```

my settings.py path:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS =  (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates"),)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"), )
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "admin")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
```

base.html:

```
  {% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head       content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../static/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../static/static/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="../static/static/css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="../static/static/css/smart_wizard.css" rel="stylesheet" >
     <link href="../static/static/css/demo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
     <link href="../static/static/css/progressbutton.css" rel="stylesheet" >
 </head>

  <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pul</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Sign Up</a></li>
               {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav><br><br><br><br><br>
  {% block head_title %}
  {% endblock %}

 {% block main_content %}
 {% endblock main_content %}
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

{% block step1 %}
 {% endblock %}
{% block step2 %}
 {% endblock %}

     <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../static/static/js/button_click.js"></script>

    <script src="../static/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../static/static/js/jquery.smartWizard.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

login.html:

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign In" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class = ' col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
<h1>{% trans "login" %}</h1>

{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}

{% if socialaccount_providers %}
<p>{% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %}Please sign in with one
of your existing third party accounts. Or, <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a>
for a {{ site_name }} account and sign in below:{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<div class="socialaccount_ballot">

  <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
    <!-- connecting login with scial account -->
    <!-- {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %} -->
  </ul>

  <div class="login-or">{% trans 'or' %}</div>

</div>

{% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}

{% else %}
<p>{% blocktrans %}If you have not created an account yet, then please
<a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a> first.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
{% endif %}

<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="btn btn-link button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
  <button class="btn btn-default primaryAction" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I still can not figure out what strange issue it is. Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You load staticfiles with `{% load staticfiles %}` but you don't use `static` template tag.

Replace all your asset links with `{% static 'path/to/file.ext' %}`

**E.g** :
replace

```
../static/static/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css
```

with this : (**if your files is a global static files**)

```
{% static 'app_name/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css' %}
```

with this : (**if your files is an app static files**)

```
{% static 'app_name/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css' %}
```

**I recommend you to read carefully Django docs : [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css)**

Comment: p.s: if `css` folder is just under `static` folder, `{% static 'css/sticky-footer-navbar.css' %}` will work, too

Comment: @Louis Barranqueiro Thank you so much! It works at last!

Comment: By the way this variant  {% static 'css/sticky-footer-navbar.css' %} not working for me. Only this one:{% static 'static/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css' %}.

Comment: that is not normal, add to your question your static folder architecture please. THese static files are global or from an app?

Comment: Louis Barranqueiro, I've added static structure, please see

Comment: ok. the problem come from your `static` directory in main `static` directory. your global static files must be at the root of `static` directory, not in `static/static` directory. Could you add your static settings? please. I recommend you to read these post to understand : [static root setup in Django 1-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851756/static-root-setup-in-django-1-8/33854613#33854613) otherwise put these static files in static file of one of your app under `app_name/static/app_name/`.